# trying to display a pdf from firebase storage in pure html and js

Tags: html, firebase

Me and a couple friends are trying to make a system where you upload a file in a admin secured dashboard, and it shows the pdf on the homepage. But we are struggling to place the pdf from firebase to the homepage. We are going to figure out the login system later, but i currently need help with just placing the pdf.

What works:
Uploading system

What needs help:
PDF Displaying system

Any help is appreciated,
thanks in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cloud Storage Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Admin Dashboard</h1>
    <div class="upload-area">
        <button class="upload">Upload</button>
        <div class="progress-container">
            <div class="progress"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="percent">0%</div>
        <div class="controls">
            <svg class="pause" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
                <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" />
                <path d="M6 19h4V5H6v14zm8-14v14h4V5h-4z" />
            </svg>
            <svg class="resume" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
                <path
                    d="M8 6.82v10.36c0 .79.87 1.27 1.54.84l8.14-5.18c.62-.39.62-1.29 0-1.69L9.54 5.98C8.87 5.55 8 6.03 8 6.82z" />
            </svg>
            <svg class="cancel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
                <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" />
                <path
                    d="M18.3 5.71c-.39-.39-1.02-.39-1.41 0L12 10.59 7.11 5.7c-.39-.39-1.02-.39-1.41 0-.39.39-.39 1.02 0 1.41L10.59 12 5.7 16.89c-.39.39-.39 1.02 0 1.41.39.39 1.02.39 1.41 0L12 13.41l4.89 4.89c.39.39 1.02.39 1.41 0 .39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41L13.41 12l4.89-4.89c.38-.38.38-1.02 0-1.4z" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <input type="file" class="hidden-upload-btn" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <!-- firebase sdk -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: it's my first time using firebase in a project, sorry if its like "too easy" for you :)

My code is down below, i purposely cleared out the api keys.

```html
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: " ",
    authDomain: " ",
    projectId: " ",
    storageBucket: " ",
    messagingSenderId: " ",
    appId: " ",
    measurementId: " "
  };
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// get dom in variables
var upload = document.getElementsByClassName('upload')[0];
var hiddenBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden-upload-btn')[0];
var progress = document.getElementsByClassName('progress')[0];
var percent = document.getElementsByClassName('percent')[0];
var pause = document.getElementsByClassName('pause')[0];
var resume = document.getElementsByClassName('resume')[0];
var cancel = document.getElementsByClassName('cancel')[0];

// create function for select a file
upload.onclick = function () {
    hiddenBtn.click();
}

// also store files path in localstorage or in database for further use
if(!localStorage.getItem("uploaded-metadata")){
    var metadata = '[]';
    localStorage.setItem('uploaded-metadata', metadata)
}

// get selected file and upload function
hiddenBtn.onchange = function () {
    // get file
    var file = hiddenBtn.files[0];
    // change file name so cannot overwrite
    var name = file.name.split('.').shift() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 10 + '.' + file.name.split('.').pop();
    var type = file.type.split('/')[0];
    var path = type + '/' + name;
    // now upload
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(path);
    var uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);

    pause.onclick = function () {
        uploadTask.pause();
        resume.style.display = 'inline-block';
        pause.style.display = 'none';
    }
    resume.onclick = function () {
        uploadTask.resume();
        resume.style.display = 'none';
        pause.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
    cancel.onclick = function () {
        uploadTask.cancel();
        progress.style.width = '0%';
        percent.innerHTML = '0%';
    }

    upload.disabled = true;
    percent.innerHTML = '0%';

    // get progressbar
    uploadTask.on('state_changed',
        (snapshot) => {
            var progressValue = String((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100).split('.')[0];
            progress.style.width = progressValue + '%';
            percent.innerHTML = progressValue + '%';
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        },
        () => {
            // on successful upload
            var metadata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('uploaded-metadata'));
            metadata.unshift(path);
            localStorage.setItem("uploaded-metadata", JSON.stringify(metadata));
            percent.innerHTML = 'DONE';
            upload.disabled = false;
            hiddenBtn.value = null;
        }
    )
}

function openUrl(v){
    var path = v.parentElement.getAttribute('data-file-name');
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(path);
    expandContainerUl.style.display = 'none';
    loader.style.display = 'block';
    storageRef.getDownloadURL()
    .then((url) => {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        console.log(url);
        return(url);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // if any error
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Comment: Its asking the user to upload a pdf, the pdf gets uploaded onto firebase, and it gets loaded back down into the html. This should be splitter into two parts, one for myself to upload, one for others to read.

Comment: The point of the project is to use firebase :|